# My flex item won't display with a javascript class toggle

Tags: javascript, flexbox

I am trying to toggle a div by calling its ID. The element is a flex item inside a flex container with initial `display` set to `none`.

```
<div id="header-menu-button" onclick="headerMenuToggle()">
    ...
</div>
<div id="header">
    ...
    <nav id="header-menu-wrapper" class="header-menu-wrapper" role="navigation" aria-label="Alternate Menu">
        ...
    </nav>
    ...
</div>

<style>
    .header {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        justify-content: space-between;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .header > * {
        -webkit-flex: 1 100%;
        -ms-flex: 1 100%;
        -moz-flex: 1 100%;
        flex: 1 100%;
    }
    .header-menu-wrapper {
        display: none;
    }
    .show {
        display:-webkit-flex;
        display:flex;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function headerMenuToggle() {
        document.getElementById("header-menu-wrapper").classList.toggle("show");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine:

```js
function headerMenuToggle() {
        document.getElementById("header-menu-wrapper").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.header {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        justify-content: space-between;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .header > * {
        -webkit-flex: 1 100%;
        -ms-flex: 1 100%;
        -moz-flex: 1 100%;
        flex: 1 100%;
    }
    .header-menu-wrapper {
        display: none;
    }
    .show {
        display:-webkit-flex;
        display:flex;
    }
```

```html
<div id="header-menu-button" onclick="headerMenuToggle()">
    header-menu-button
</div>
<div id="header">
    header
    <nav id="header-menu-wrapper" class="header-menu-wrapper" role="navigation" aria-label="Alternate Menu">
        header-menu-wrapper
    </nav>
    header
</div>
```